# Create a post in Blogger with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, blogger, urlfetch

So far I haven't found a good code to create posts in Blogger with Google Script.

In the API Console I got the following credentials:

- Client ID
- Client Secret
- API key

Also, libraries were added to the Google Script:

- OAuth2 library → MswhXl8fVhTFUH_Q3UOJbXvxhMjh3Sh48
- Blogger library → M2CuWgtxF1cPLI9mdRG5_9sh00DPSBbB3

I tried some codes, and this is the current one:

```
function create_blog_post() {
  var payload =
      {
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "blog": {
          "id": "12345........" // YOUR_BLOG_ID
        },
        "title": "New post",
        "content": "With content..."
      };
var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken(), // ← THIS IS WRONG
    "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PATCH"
  };
  var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "headers" : { "Authorization" : "Bearer" + getService().getAccessToken()},
        "contentType" : "application/json",
        "payload" : '{ "kind": "blogger#post", "blog": { "id": "12345........" }, "title": "New post", "content": "With content..." }'
      };
  try {
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/12345......../posts", options);
    Logger.log(result);
    } catch (e) {Logger.log(e);}
}
```

Please help me solve this with the simplest code possible.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail information `THIS IS WRONG`? If your script has more issues, can you provide them?

Comment: The error message for the line marked with «THIS IS WRONG» is like so: ReferenceError: "getService" is not defined. (line 13, file "crear_post_blog")

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, is this document useful? https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2

Comment: You need to use [tag:urlfetch] not gapi. gapi only works client side. Search the urlfetch tag  for samples on sending authorization headers to blogger api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Required reading:

- [ScriptApp#getOauthToken](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken())
- [Blogger §post#insert](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert)
- [UrlFetchApp#fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app.html#fetch(String,Object))
- [Editing manifest#Setting explicit scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)
- [Switch to standard GCP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)
- [API Library](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library)

#### Issue:

- Usage of asynchronous client side browser samples in the synchronous server side.

#### Solution:

- It is possible to access Blogger api from Google apps script  using `UrlFetchApp`
- Full OAuth flow can be bypassed using oauth token provided by `ScriptApp`
- Include scopes in the appsscript.json manifest file.
- Switch to a standard GCP and enable the blogger api

#### Snippet:

```js
function createBlogPost(){
  var postUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts";
  var blogId = /*"YOUR_BLOG_ID"*/;
  postUrl = postUrl.replace("blogId",blogId);
  var options = {
    method:"post",
    contentType:"application/json",
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      title: "Hello from Apps Script!",
      content: "This post is automatically created by Apps script"
    })
  }
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(postUrl, options).getContentText();
  console.log(res);//or Logger.log(res)
}
```

Manifest scopes:

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, TheMaster. The first error message is **`Missing } after property list. (line 10, file "Code")`**, so I added a comma at the end of **`headers:`** line. Then, when running the code the error message for **`UrlFetchApp`** is **`Request failed for https : // www . googleapis . com returned code 403...`**. How can this be solved?

Comment: @Julio Did you add the scopes?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes I did → "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]

Comment: Added the oauthScopes to the appsscript.json.

Comment: @Julio I see you gave the bounty. So, did it work? Do you still have a problem (403)?

Comment: It's not working yet, but since you are the only one who is helping... When offering the bounty I thought there would be at least three people assisting with the question, but it's not the case.

Comment: @Julio  You should've waited. Others might've jumped in later. Send ``{muteHttpOptions:true}`` in ``options``. And examine the full response with `Logger.log(res)`  and post it here/in your question. I've edited my answer to reflect the modifications. Don't forget to [enable the api](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library)

Comment: @Julio Also, you need to enable api for this apps script project. For this, you need to [switch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) to a standard gcp project(say "blogStandard"). After switching, you can enable blogger api for blogStandard.

Comment: I enabled the API and associated the script with a project number and authorized it. NOW IT'S WORKING! Thanks a lot **TheMaster**, this is going to be useful for many others. :)

Comment: Perfect answer, Thank you so much, Earlier I used post by Email method which was inefficient, This is a better method