# Google Apps Script - How to stream JSON data into BigQuery?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-apps-script-addon, jsonlines

In this reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery,

In order to load CSV data into BigQuery, they use:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(csvFileId);
  var data = file.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream');

  // Create the data upload job.
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        skipLeadingRows: 1
      }
    }
  };
  job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
```

As I understand, they send a blob to BigQuery `file.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream');`, which is not friendly

**How to send a JSON to BigQuery in Apps Script?**

With the library `@google-cloud/bigquery` (using in a project outside of Apps Script), I can do something like this:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples

```
// Import the Google Cloud client library
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')
const moment = require('moment')

exports.insertUsageLog = async (userId) => {
  const datasetId = 'usage'
  const tableId = 'logs'
  const rows = [
    // The JSON data is collected here
    {
      timestamp: moment.utc().toISOString(),
      userId,
      // Something else ...
    },
  ]

  // Create a client
  const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery()

  // Insert data into a table
  await bigqueryClient
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows)
  console.log(`Inserted ${rows.length} rows`)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data payload to `BigQuery.Jobs.insert()` has to be a blob.

You can create that blob from either CSV content or a [newline delimited JSON](http://jsonlines.org/). Newline delimited JSON is a distinct form of JSON that is [required by BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json). It is not natively supported by Apps Script. However, you should be able to convert standard JSON to that format by creating a custom [`replacer` function and passing it as a parameter to `JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter). Alternatively, you might be able to leverage an existing Javascript library (you might be able to find something via NPM or just doing a search on Github).

Once you've generated a newline delimited JSON (as either a string or a byte array) you'll need to convert it to a blob using `Utilities.newBlob()` and pass it to the `BigQuery.Jobs.insert()` method.

Comment: Note that Newline delimited json is NOT a json in and of itself, but it's a list of valid json separated by new lines.

Comment: @Dimu Designs: Thanks. Because the data sent to BigQuery must be blob, so as I understand, the library `@google-cloud/bigquery` will handle all these tasks that you mentioned for us? You can check the example here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples.

Comment: Btw, I checked this article https://hackernoon.com/json-lines-format-76353b4e588d and I finally know why BigQuery uses ndjson

Comment: @Dimu Designs: There are some packages on npm that support ndjson, but for Apps Script, I can not find anything. Can you suggest a function to do the job?

Comment: Dimu and @TheMaster: I got another error "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.insert failed with error: Insufficient Permission". Both the apps script project and the big query are under the same GCP project, also I don't see where to configure the service account for apps script, so I thought it should have the permission automatically, right?

Comment: @Hoang Setting required scopes might help. See references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58025407/)

Comment: @TheMaster: This is my appsscript.json https://prnt.sc/p90ba3. I had scope "script.external_request"

Comment: @Hoang Add big query scopes as seen in bigquery.insert documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199762/discussion-between-hoang-trinh-and-themaster).

Comment: This worked for getting rid of the newlines in a json string  jsonText= jsonText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");