# How many service calls am I allowed in a day?

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've set up two sets of address. One across the second row starting at B2 and another down the first column starting at A3. Using a custom function invoking google's api I am trying to get a list of drive times in minutes for all locations in the first column to all locations in the second row. I get an error stating that it has ran to many times in one day. Here is the custom function

```
function DriveTime(origin, destination) {
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .getDirections();
  return directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value/60;  
}
```

> Error: Service invoked too many times in one day: route (line 2)

I understand the error, but how many times in one day can I make this call as a standard free user. And where can I find pricing to increase the amount of daily calls to this service?

Also if anyone knows of a way to accomplish this in less calls than I am attempting, that'd be welcomed knowledge as well.

Comment: Looks like the direction api pricing is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing

Comment: There are no "free" users.  You might not be charged (you get a credit), but you **have** to set up billing with a credit card.  Without one, you typically get ~1 query.

Comment: You can consult your quota in your Google Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your quota as a apps script user without API key/Billing information should be zero. But for whatever reason, Google didn't make changes to charge apps script Maps library when they [changed the pricing back in June'18 for everything else related to Maps API](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html). There seems to be a default quota, which is not explicitly mentioned in apps script documentation pages.

If you have had premium plan in the past, you can leverage [`Maps.setAuthentication()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps.html#setAuthentication(String,String)). But if you do not,

> This method doesn't work with API keys. Additionally, please note that Premium Plan is no longer available for new customers. If you don't already have a Premium Plan license, please don't call setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey). You are able to use the Maps methods with the default quota allowances.

Which means you cannot extend the default quota allowance.

Your alternative would then be to [call the maps api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) directly[<sup>skip oauth</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979124) using [urlfetch](/questions/tagged/urlfetch)app and parse the response using apps script vanilla javascript(es5).

You can see the [pricing here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/).