# Showing errors while creating Google Maps URL from a Sheets using App Scripts?

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have latitude and longitude values in a Google Sheet and I want to draw a Google Map URL using App Scripts. I have a paid Google Maps API key but can't find ways to integrate it with my App Scripts code in the Script Editor?

While executing the codes, it shows error message,

> "The Google Maps Platform server
> rejected your request. You must use an API key to authenticate each
> request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information,
> please refer to [http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"](http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account%22)

The codes are as follows:

```
    function mappingLoc() {
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
        var tempdataset = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TempDataSet');
    
        var data = tempdataset.getLastRow();
        var latis = [];
        var latis = tempdataset.getRange(2, 4, data).getValues();  
    
        var longis = [];
        var longis = tempdataset.getRange(2, 5, data).getValues();        
          
        //var map = Maps.newStaticMap().addMarker(latis, longis);
        var map=latis.reduce((map,[lat],i)=>map.addMarker(Number(lat),Number(longis[i][0])),Maps.newStaticMap());
        dashboard.getRange("A71").setValue(map.getMapUrl());          
     }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136269/

Answer (score 0):

### The free usage of the Static Maps API has limits

See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/usage-and-billing):
[image]

There is also a lmit for  [Maximum Queries per Second (QPS): 500](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/usage-and-billing#authenticating-requests)

In other words:

**If you perform more than 100 000 requests per month or more than 500 requests per second you will be required to pay.**

If you are interested: [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key) you can find information about how to set-up a billing account and obtaining an API key for the paid service.

Alternatively:

Reduce the total amount of your requests and especially the request speed to keep using the Static Maps API for free.

Comment: what is request means here? For instance I have 500 sets of longitude and latitude and I generate a link and then I click on the link to draw a map of 500 point. Is it a single request or 500 requests? Sorry, I am not clear about your comments, "Reduce the total amount of your requests and especially the request speed to keep using the Static Maps API for free." Please clarify.

Comment: For example `map.addMarker()` is a request. So if you perform this request for each value of `var latis = tempdataset.getRange(2, 4, data).getValues();` - the amount request corresponds to the size of `data`.  SAme for `longis~. In other words, you need to rewrite your cpode in suhc a way that you perform less then 500 requests per second.

Comment: This is part of an attendance system. My number of request is always less than 500 per second. I have 100 students per class, so 200 specific location data. What I want is, after taking attendance of a particular class of 100 students, the code will generate a map pointing locations of the students to detect unfair means. It is a voluntary project, so teachers cannot pay money here. Thus I have to keep it free. Could you please assist in modifying the above code?

Comment: You can implement between your requests a [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) call to decrease your request rate. See if e.g. 100 ms works for you. Be careful though not to exceed the [ maximum script execution time](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).

Comment: @ziganotscchka I made the hardcoding var data = 10, so the total data data requests will be 20. Do I need to configure the MAP API even it is within the free limit. Still showing the message, he Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs.

Comment: In this case you might have exceed the monthly volume range. I suggest you to go to your GCP console to check your usage as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota). If you are a GSuite user, you are also entited to [GSuiste support](https://gsuite.google.com/support) and can ask which quota exactly you exceeded.

Comment: I created the Google MAP API but still the same issue. Then I searched several documents and I think I need to integrate MAP API key in the App scripts code at the Script Editor. I found some code for JavaScript but did not find any for App Scripts. Please check the codes above the mappingLoc() at my post and advise accordingly. In the URL the api key should be included, I think.

Comment: You can have a look at one of the already existing samples of how to implement an API key in Apps Script, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948812/set-maps-api-key-in-script-editor).

Comment: @ziganotschka I have already checked it before doing this post. It can't solve my issue as it is totally different scenario. Could you please modify my codes and advise me.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo my post is still within the scope of the original question. The same error message it shows as what I posted in my post from the very beginning. Need a specific solution really. So it is not further queries in addition to my original question. Thanks

Comment: @TamjidTaha: The answer to the question I linked shows very well how to implement an API key into an Apps Script request to Maps APi. If you think that it does not solve your issue, you should either create a new post or at least edit your exisitng question explaining in detail how you tried to implement this approach yourself and where you encountered problems. Stackoverflow is not free codewriting service, so you cannot ask people to simply modify your code for you.

Comment: @ziganotschka you are an expert in this area and it won't take much time but believe me or not, I am trying to solve it for the last one month or more. TheMaster is another expert in stackoverflow who said above that this post is a duplicate, previously told me that it is not possible to draw a map. Based on your documentation and my previously studied materials I am sure it is possible. Yesterday I paid for Google Maps API key.  If you look at the error message, it said EACH Request, "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs".  Post modified, plz help.