# How to get the 1st date and last date of the current Week as well as Month in the format of 'yyyy-mm-dd' using App Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out the 1st date and last date of the current week as well as the 1st date and last date of the current month in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` using Google App scripts. `Date()` seems to be a difficult object for me, therefore seeking advice. Please consider Saturday is the starting day and Friday is the end day of a week in this parts of the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [toLocaleString("sv-SE")](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocalestring_date_all) to convert the date to the desired format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Try this:

```js
const today = new Date(); 
const firstWeekD = today.getDate() - today.getDay()-1; 
const lastWeekD = firstWeekD + 6; 
const firstdayOfWeek = new Date(today.setDate(firstWeekD)).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10);
const lastdayOfWeek = new Date(today.setDate(lastWeekD)).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10);
const date = new Date();
const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10);
const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).toLocaleString("sv-SE").slice(0,10);
  
console.log(firstdayOfWeek); // first day of the week - Saturday
console.log(lastdayOfWeek); // last day of the week - Friday
console.log(firstDayOfMonth) // first day of the month
console.log(lastDayOfMonth) // last day of the month
```

Comment: Marios could you please check my recent post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040083/showing-errors-while-creating-google-maps-url-from-a-sheets-using-app-scripts/64044934?noredirect=1#comment113282004_64044934

Answer (score 3):

### Get first (Saturday) and last (Friday) date of this week

You can use [`Date.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to get the current day of the week (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, etc.).  But there is no method `Date.setDay()` so we need to do a little math to figure out how many days ago the most recent Saturday was, and use [`Date.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate):

```
// Get the Date for the Saturday on or preceding the current date.
var saturday = new Date(); // Today
var day = date.getDay(); // Day of week (0-6)
var newDay = date.getDate() - ((day + 1) % 7);  // The day of the month we want.
saturday.setDate(newDay); // Our date object for Saturday.
```

`(day + 1) % 7` calculates how many days to subtract; for example, if today is Sunday (day=0), we need to go back one day: `(0 + 1) % 7 = 1`.  But if today is Saturday (day=6), we get `(6 + 1) % 7 = 0` and we don't subtract any days.

The routine for finding the upcoming Friday is similar, but we add days instead of subtracting:

```
// Get the Date for the Friday on or after the given date.
var friday = new Date(date); // today
var day = date.getDay();
var diff = date.getDate() + ((5 - day) % 7); 
friday.setDate(diff);
```

---

### Get first and last date of this month

This is simpler using [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), since it takes as its parameter the day of the month.

```
var firstOfMonth = new Date(); // today
firstOfMonth.setDate(1); // Sets the day to the first of the month
```

To get the last of the month, we go ahead one month, then back to the last day of the previous month (the last of this month):

```
var lastOfMonth = new Date(); 
lastOfMonth.setMonth(lastOfMonth.getMonth()+1);  // Go ahead one month
lastOfMonth.setDate(0); // Sets to 1 day before the first of the month, i.e. the last of this month.
```

---

### Convert to format 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Google Apps Script has a built-in method for formatting dates: [`Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, format)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

`date` is a Date object, `timezone` is a string such as those from the [TZ database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), and `format` is a string in [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

For example:

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(friday, 'America/Denver', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

(Note the capital `MM` for month because `mm` represents minutes.)