# How to make a column range of a pivot table dynamic using Google App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a column range `[A13:A57]` at a pivot table having email addresses of users. The END of column range `[A57]` may change but its beginning is always `[A13]`. If there is NO value in the column range it won't do anything.

> It is showing error, `getRange()` is not defined. If I use `[A13:A57]`
> directly, it works but I need to make the range dynamic. Don't find
> any issue in the code! Part of the whole code is given below:

```
const ssd = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh_db = ssd.getSheetByName('Dashboard');

var range = sh_db.getRange("A13:A").getValues();
var filtered_r = range.filter(String).length;    
if(filtered_r > 0){

  const u_emails = sh_db.getRange(13,1,filtered_r,1).getValues().flat(); 
  const data = sh_tds.getRange('A1:G'+sh_tds.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var std = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'MMM/YYYY');
}
```

Comment: @Marios See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309373

Comment: @TheMaster `The problem does not directly involve Google's APIs or Google Apps Script services. Examples might be array or string manipulation questions.` The accepted answer in this post is clearly a javascript array manipulation (using filter and forEach). I think tag javascript should be part of this question. The other two answers are not related to javascript I agree since they solely involve Google api.

Comment: @Marios I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

**You can consider only the cells that are not empty.**

Get the full column:

`const range = sh_db.getRange("A13:A").getValues().flat();`

And then the **non empty** email list will be:

`const u_emails  = range.filter(row=> row!='');`

As a result, `u_emails` is an array with non empty elements and therefore you can iterate over it without issues.

---

### Solution:

```
  const ssd = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh_db = ssd.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  const range = sh_db.getRange("A13:A").getValues().flat();

  const u_emails  = range.filter(row=> row!='');

  if(u_emails.length > 0){
    const data = sh_tds.getRange('A1:G'+sh_tds.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var std = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'MMM/YYYY');
  }
```

and then you can iterate over `u_emails` like that:

```
u_emails.forEach(email=>{               
     MailApp.sendEmail(email,"subject","message/body");              
  });
```

Comment: could you please check my another post relating to Google map at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040083/showing-errors-while-creating-google-maps-url-from-a-sheets-using-app-scripts

Comment: @TamjidTaha I am not familiar with google maps but I will check it out. I don't even have access to the maps api

Answer (score 2):

#### Logic:

- Get all pivot tables in a sheet - [Sheet#getPivotTables](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getpivottables).
- If the sheet only has 1 pivot table or you know the index of the pivot table, it's easy to get the range  using [Pivot table #getSourceDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-table#getsourcedatarange)
- If not, get anchor cell the pivot table is hinged to and  check whether it is the cell you're looking for - [PivotTable#getAnchorCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-table#getanchorcell)

#### Snippet:

```
const sh_db = ssd.getSheetByName('Dashboard'),
     pts = sh_db.getPivotTables(),
     pt = pts[0],//or use pts.find(pt=>pt.getAnchorCell().getA1Notation()==="A13"),
     ptRg = pt.getSourceDataRange();//use Range.offset() to restrict the range further to A13:A{lr} if needed.
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that you can select the pivot tables like that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define an endpoint for the range, or it won't work. In order to do what you need to, you'll need to have the script find out how many rows of data it's working with. Once you've defined that, use the variable in your range call.

```
var lastRow = sh_db.getLastRow();
var range = sh_db.getRange("A13:A" + lastRow).getValues();
```

Comment: Sorry, it will not work as my other columns in the same sheets has more values than column A. As it is a pivot table, I think when the first row in column A starting from A13 is blank, it may be possible to count the end of the range.