# 403 accessing programatically created sheets project endpoint through Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-403, google-apps-script-api

Used code to create a blank spreadsheet and obtain it's Id. Once the Id of the resource is available I want to attach a custom script to it programmatically.

```
  [...]
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Опис "+dateFormated);
  
  Logger.log(newSpreadsheet.getId());
```

```
  var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/'+newSpreadsheet.getId();
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });
```

the request results in an error (regardless of which endpoint I call for project)
The URL provided in the error message is unhelpful as it's not a project I manage. Going to it results in

> You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page
>
> You are missing at least one of the following required permissions:
>
> Project
>
> resourcemanager.projects.get
>
> serviceusage.services.get

```
 "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Apps Script API has not been used in project 85798724816 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/script.googleapis.com/overview?project=85798724816 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/script.googleapis.com/overview?project=85798724816"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**EDIT:** Both the answer from puffin and TheMaster solve the problem.

The answer from TheMaster is what I wanted to do more specifically

There is also a problem with my question. I am trying to get the project for the spreadsheet before one is even created. So the correct first request to make is "POST" to "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects"

The solution steps:

1. switch from "default" Google cloud project to "standard" cloud project (check the link from TheMaster)
2. Create an API key in cloud console for the project
3. 

```
  var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects?key=[YOUR_KEY_HERE]';
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var data = {
    "parentId": "16eL4PIVFO5Zdd7r-8HhQF_4OZS7G7TbTX-pg",
    "title": "autoProject"
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify(data),
  });
```

and that's how you perform a successful request to the Scripts API from Scripts itself

Comment: Is this gsuite? You probably need to ask your admin  to grant those privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If this is gsuite, You probably need to ask your admin  to grant those privileges.
- If you're sure you have privileges, you need to [switch from "default"  Google cloud project to "standard" cloud  project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)
- [Enable the api](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library) for the created "standard" GCP
- [Project scopes need to be added to manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)
- [Related answer and comment chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58025407)

Answer (score 0):

First, to get the url of the spreadsheet, you can simply call the [`getUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl) method, which returns a full url to the spreadsheet as a string:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Logger.log(ss.getUrl());
```

Once you do this, you have the right idea of using the `SriptApp` service, but you are going about the specifics of attaching a script at runtime wrong. To attach a function to the sheet, you need to create a new [`Trigger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger) (which are effective just callbacks which are called given certain conditions) using the [`TriggerBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder):

```js
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
  .forSpreadsheet(ss) // you can also use the spreadsheet id here
  .onOpen()
  .create();
```

It is important to note that you want to pass the in the desired function name as a **string** not a callback.

To do this you will need the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp` authorization scope, or you will receive more runtime errors, which you can view in the google script projects dashboard.

For more info please read [Authorization Scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) and [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)