# Deploying Script as Webapp directly from Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-403, google-apps-script-api

Is it, at all, possible to deploy a Google Scripts as web app directly from Google Sheets?

I am trying to add a custom menu to Google Sheets where the user can programmatically deploy the file's script as a web app. And it looks like it is possible to do so by following instructions from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/RomainVialard/programmatically-deploy-a-web-app).

But for obvious reasons, I need to set `projectId` to equal `ScriptApp.getScriptId()`, so that when the Spreadsheet file is copied, this variable is dynamically set to equal to that script's unique id. However, when executing `saveAndDeployNewVersion()` from the custom menu I've set up (and even from inside the script itself) I always get `deploymentId` returned as undefined, before getting a 403 error from the final function in the chain (`makeRequest_`).

Is there any other approach, OR, can you point out what I'm doing wrong when implementing this script into my own project?

> Request failed for https://script.googleapis.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Apps Script API has not been used in project 575477635395 before or it is disabled. Enable it by vi... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 211, file "Code")

Comment: 403 is authorization problem. Have you included the required scopes in manifest?

Comment: Can you please post the full error message?

Comment: @TheMaster, I have. Exactly as specified in the repo.

Comment: @Alessandro, that's the other issue. i get a truncated message and can't figure out a way to see the whole thing. I already tried setting `muteHttpExceptions` to true. But that simply hides the error message. This is all I am able to see: `Request failed for https://script.googleapis.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Apps Script API has not been used in project 575477635395 before or it is disabled. Enable it by vi... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 211, file "Code")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1. [Switch to standard GCP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project).
2. [Enable the apps script api for that GCP](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library)

Also see [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58025407/).

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you so much! There are just two other issue that this brought up. Every time I make a copy of the original Spreadsheet, the script is obviously coped too and I am required to manually re-associate to the GCP. Also, the url I get from `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` no longer works as the new url pattern takes the authorized domain into account. Any idea how to solve these, or point me to the right direction?

Comment: @Byron Kindly make a separate post for each of those questions after sufficient research. But those two are not easy to solve(if at all).